# Eclipse: Restart an SVN import from where it left off?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I've got an SVN import that keeps breaking off in the middle, generating `RA layer request failed...Could not read response body: Connection was closed by server`.

It breaks off at different spots each time, making me think it's a timeout issue.

I'm new to SVN so bear with me, but is there a way to pick up the import where I left off?

My gut is telling me this is against the whole concept of SVN but my gut's been wrong before. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, any action in svn is atomic and all of them either are done completely or should be rolled back. This problem is mainly because of connections to the svn server. See [this post](http://lists.freepascal.org/fpc-devel/2009-July/017007.html). It may be helpful.